# App freezes or crashes while capturing image

Tags: ios, codenameone

Trying to capture image  on iOS device for that I use Camera API available. But after capturing few images sometimes the app freezes on use photo/ retake screen. Whilst it also takes location while capturing image. But on freeze the screen rotates but can't press any button and I need to kill the app and retake pictures again.

May I know the reason behind this?

Comment: Which device and iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep references to the existing images this sounds like you are running out of memory. You can use the [native logging cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html) to track the device output during situations such as these.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response, I tried to add native logs over there, but I dont get any error for app crashing even I checked on XCode, I dont get anything. I have two buttons camera and gallery. If I select image from gallery save it works fine then capture image using camera, it captures image and default preview screen opens as Retake and UsePhoto, the app just halts there until I kill it. This occurs only on iPad Mini. Its simple code just to capture image and display.

Comment: You don't see any printouts in xcode??? If you run in xcode without the native logging do you see something? Which version of xcode?

Comment: I do see the printouts, but I dont see any error related to crashing of app or why the camera halts after taking picture. I am using Xcode 9.4.1 version.

Comment: You should run on xcode 9.2 which is what we use in the servers. You can download it from Apples developer site. If the app freezes you can press pause and look at the stack traces to see where the threads are stuck If you can't make sense of them you can copy the stacks and paste them into the question then comment here so I can see the update